# Как динамически добавлять элементы к массиву? js

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, методы, push

> Не понимаю, почему здесь массив не добавляет к себе элементы, а постоянно меняет одно значение и его длинна так и остаётся 1. Буду благодарен за подсказку

```
for(let i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    seats[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        let seatsAtr = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-info');
        seatsAtr = JSON.parse(seatsAtr);
        selectSeats(seatsAtr);

        function selectSeats(seat) {
            let seatsItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('seats'));
            
            let arrSeats = [];
            arrSeats.push(seat);
            console.log(arrSeats);
        
            localStorage.setItem('seats', JSON.stringify(seat));
        }       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого используют метод .push() на переменной вне функции, меняя локальную переменную, при новом вызове ее уже нет.
Вынеси создание списка за функцию.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function selectSeats(seat) {
      let seats = [];
      if (localStorage.getItem('seats'))
        seats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('seats'));
        
      seats.push(seat);
      console.log(seats);
    
      localStorage.setItem('seats', JSON.stringify(seats));
    }
```